# Yii CMenu active class not showing - why?

Tags: yii, cmenu

I'm rendering this Cmenu but the active class isn't showing on the li element when we are active on that menu page.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', 
     array('items'=>array(
         array(
           'label'=>'Foo',
           'url'=>array('event/index/21')
         ),
         array(
            'label'=>'Bar',
            'url'=>array('event/index/22')
         )
       )
      )
 );
```

**Does anyone knows why ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'url'=>array('event/index', array( 'event' => '21' ))
```

This works.

It seems that it's the routes that need to match for the active class to kick in.

*ref:*
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/23317-cmenu-item-not-active-any-more-after-i-used-url-cheating/